# How to customize org-babel RESULTS

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I would like to load TODO objects from individual files using org-babel and elisp. I have a working snippet that produces this output.

```
#+RESULTS: import_file
:   * TODO Go to grocery store
:   * TODO Go to bank
:   * TODO Go to dry cleaners
```

The `:` in the output causes org-mode not to recognize the TODO keywords. I want the output to look like this:

```
#+RESULTS: import_file
* TODO Go to grocery store
* TODO Go to bank
* TODO Go to dry cleaners
```

Is there an org-babel configuration item that accomplishes this? If not, is there another way to accomplish this without modifying org-babel?

Comment: If you want results to be inserted without any kind of formatting, then you would add that information to the source block header, viz. `:results raw`. The problem with this method is that repeated calls to the same block will not remove the previous results. You could also use `:result org`, which would insert it as a Org source (editable as other source blocks). Also, see this: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/header-args.html

Comment: I need an option of both raw and replace. `:results org` produces comma delimited output for some reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry, this is super old, but I thought I'd post the solution for people who find this in the future.

use `:wrap "x"`

Put whatever text you want in for x.
This gives similar results for raw, but doesn't have the repeating issue.

```
#+name: hello-world 
#+BEGIN_SRC latex :wrap "test"
\LaTeX
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: hello-world
#+BEGIN_test
\LaTeX
#+END_test
```